# Skew symmetric $4\times 4$ matrix of full-rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have come across the fact that a $4\times 4$ skew-symmmetric matrix of full-rank is equivalent to 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 &\theta_1& 0 &0 \\ -\theta_1& 0 &0 &0 \\ 0& 0&0 & \theta_2 \\ 0& 0& -\theta_2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
And I'm not sure why. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean "equivalent"? What are "equivalent matrices"

Comment: I think similar matrices, like a change of basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: The eigenvalues of a real skew-symmetric matrix are pure imaginary and come in pairs of $(\lambda_k, - \lambda_k)$.

Comment: Thanks! So this means that the companion matrix of the corresponding block is $x^2 +\lambda^2$ ($\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$) which has corresponding matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\lambda^2\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$ (using rational canonical form) which can be converted to $\begin{pmatrix} 0& \lambda\\ -\lambda&0\end{pmatrix}$ under a simple change of basis. And then do this for the other block.

Answer (score 1):

For a proof of this see the article [Normal forms for skew-symmetric matrices](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fproc%2F1988-104-03%2FS0002-9939-1988-0964872-9%2FS0002-9939-1988-0964872-9.pdf&ei=YmHLVOH3IsHjO530gLAO&usg=AFQjCNFs_5No8XPB69KDQqAsqQCFyWjzXQ&bvm=bv.84607526,d.ZWU&cad=rja), Proposition $2.1$. In particular, every skew-symmetric matrix in $M_4(\mathbb{R})$ of rank $4$ is congruent to
$$
J_4(4)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here $A$ and $B$ are *congruent*, if $B=PAP^T$ for some $P\in GL_4$.

Comment: Thanks. This is an interesting proof as well.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde , the result requested by the OP is well-known ; yet I don't understand your argument (I am not well awakened). You write that a vector space formed by skew-matrices with full rank (except $0$) is a line. How to deduct the requested result ?

Comment: @loupblanc I wanted to use the result of [this discussion](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121615/subspace-of-skew-symmetric-matrices-of-rank-four), but a direct proof seems much better.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde , I read the link to MO. Clearly the maximum dimension of  a vector space formed by skew-matrices with full rank (except $0$) over $\mathbb{R}$ is not $n-3=1$ but is $2$ (that is the result of David Speyer).